# error: pip: command not found : in xshell run "pip -h"

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, ubuntu, pip

I have installed pip, python, and other environments in my server (ubuntu), but when using xshell to connect to the server, when running at the end point, pip -h prompts command not found. What is the reason? What should I do?

These commands can be run at the server end point[server end point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUqLn.png)(pip or python).
But,These commands cannot be run at the end point of a remote connection to the server using xshell(`pip` or `python`),interesting,can run `ls` or `bash` Some system commands
[xshell end point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yN8u.png)

What should I do? can run pip or python command in xshell end point!!!

I, searched some blogs and don't know why, maybe it's because the shell connection doesn't load global environment variables? But I don't know how to fix this problem.

i hope can run pip or python command in xhsell end point!!!